# Arc length does not change with a reparametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that the arc length of a curve doesn't change with a reparametrization.

Let $\sigma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^{3}, \;g: [c,d]\to[a,b]$ and $\alpha: [c,d]\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$. $\alpha(s)=(\sigma(g(s))$.

The length of the curve $\sigma$ is $L\sigma =\int_{a}^{b} \left\lVert \sigma'(t) \right\rVert dt$, if $t=g(s)$ then $dt=g'(s)ds$

So $L\sigma=\int_{c}^{d} \left\lVert\sigma'(g(s)) \right\rVert g'(s)ds$, if $g'(s)\gt 0$, then

$L\sigma=\int_{c}^{d} \left\lVert\sigma'(g(s)) g'(s)\right\rVert ds = \int_{c}^{d} \left\lVert\alpha' (s)\right\rVert ds= L\alpha$

But i don't know how to proceed if $g'(s)\lt 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not applying the change of variables properly. You get $L_{\sigma} =\int_c^{d} \|\sigma'(g(s))\||g'(s)|\, ds$. Also $\|\sigma'(g(s))g'(s)\|=\|\sigma'(g(s))\| |g'(s)|$.

Comment: So $\frac{dg(s)}{ds} = \left\lvert g'(s)\right\rvert $ ?

Comment: $\frac {dg(s)} {ds} =g'(s)$ but in the change of variable formula you have to multiply by $|\frac {dg(s)} {ds}|$, not $\frac {dg(s)} {ds}$.